# Mobx Autorun running too often / need it to skip in some cases / run only after finished

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I know its not best practice but its the most performant solution I have found so far. It monitors an object, and transforms that object in the autorun.

This setup is working excellently for small data sets, but when there are a lot of changes, it gets stuck in the "100 cycles and didn't settle" error.

I was wondering if there was some way to get it to iterate just once / collate all changes and apply them in one hit.

I have tried a number of solutions / workarounds that involve timers, deep object comparison (ie don't run if it hasn't changed) etc, but they either disable the autorun or lead to extremely bad performance.

I guess in summary:

- Is there some way to make autorun not execute changes on the same frame?
- Is there a better solution for autorun to watch every observable in an object?
- Is there a way to limit autorun?
- Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to say anything useful without some minimal code example of what you are doing. But it sounds like you are reading and modifying the same data in the autorun, which introduces cycles. Consider using `reaction` which allows you to better separate what data you want to listen react, versus the action you want to take once a change occurs

Comment: Ahh.. Help from the creator! - it looks exactly what I was looking for, i'll give it a go and report back. Not sure how I missed in the docs

Comment: After implementing, it definitely fixes my problem, thank you!